# React Router V4 HashRouter not storing history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am building a react app in which i am using react-router v4. I have my router defined properly like this.

```
 <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Switch>
                {/* Login Route */}
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
                <Route exact path="/?redirect=:id" component={LoginForm} />
                <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/signuppage/create" component={SignUpPage} />
                <Route path="/t-and-c" component={TCPage} />
            </Switch>
        </Provider>
</Router>
```

Now when I go to signup page from the home and go to T&C page from the signup page now If I press the browser back button it is forwarding me to the `HomePage` at `/home` route.
I am using react-router v4.2.0.

All is working fine till I don't use redux as I add redux in my project that breaks the browser back button.

Here are my Components

`HomePage.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export interface IHomePageProps {
    companyName: string;
}

export class HomePageImpl extends React.PureComponent<IHomePageProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello {this.props.companyName}</h1>
            <Link to="/signuppage/create">SignUp</Link>
        </div>
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        companyName: state.companyName
    }
};

export const HomePage = connect<{}, {}, IHomePageProps>(mapStateToProps)(HomePageImpl)
```

`SingUpPage.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export interface ISignUpPageProps {
    companyName: string;
}

export class SignUpPageImpl extends React.PureComponent<ISignUpPageProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello {this.props.companyName}</h1>
            <Link to="t-and-c">T &amp; C</Link>
        </div>
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        companyName: state.companyName
    }
};

export const SignUpPage = connect<{}, {}, ISignUpPageProps>(mapStateToProps)(SignUpPageImpl)
```

`TCPage.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export interface ITCPageProps {
    companyName: string;
    terms: string;
}

export class TCPageImpl extends React.PureComponent<ITCPageProps, {}> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello {this.props.companyName}</h1>
            <p>{this.props.terms}</p>
        </div>
    }
}

export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        companyName: state.companyName,
        terms: state.terms
    }
};

export const TCPage = connect<{}, {}, ITCPageProps>(mapStateToProps)(TCPageImpl)
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `<Provider>` / `<Router>` components you have wrapping  your `<Routes>` / `<Switch>` goes in an index.js file.

In my projects, I have the provider, wrapping the BrowserRouter component like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './Containers/App/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from './store';

const StoreInstance = Store();

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={StoreInstance}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Not sure if the way you have done it is just another way of doing it or potentially causing issues.